# azure function using app services and with access to Microsoft Dynamic 365 CRM online

Tags: c#, azure, function, dynamics-crm-online

I have an Azure function that is working.  However, I am trying to also use the azure function to do authentication to get access to Microsoft Dynamic CRM.

When trying to get my token is when my problem occurs.

I hope someone can help me get this working.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.WebServiceClient;

namespace LanguageFunction
{
    public static class LanguageFunctionPlugin
    {

       [FunctionName("LanguageFunctionPlugin")]
       public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, 
TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // parse query parameter
           string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
               .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
               .Value;


            string organizationUrl = "https://xxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com";
            string api = "https://xxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1";

            AuthenticationParameters ap = AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromUrlAsync(
                new Uri(api)).Result;

            var clientId = "833ab393-56ef-6ed6-10e7-89accb8fea8b";
            var secertKey = ".N:?.h6NfT3FVCNcfdvzfbZzPZguq6t3";

            var creds = new ClientCredential(clientId, secertKey);
            log.Info("client:" + clientId);

            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ap.Authority);
            var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ap.Resource, creds).Result.AccessToken;

            log.Info("Token : " + token);

            Uri serviceUrl = new Uri(organizationUrl + @"/xrmservices/2011/organization.svc/web?SdkClientVersion=v9.1");

            using (var sdkService = new OrganizationWebProxyClient(serviceUrl, false))
            {
                sdkService.HeaderToken = token;

                var _orgService = (IOrganizationService)sdkService != null ? (IOrganizationService)sdkService : null;
                log.Info("Get Org Service");
            }

            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
   }
```

}

Comment: and what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below article and try to replicate the code provided on github repo.
https://github.com/jlattimer/CrmWebApiCSharp/blob/master/CrmWebApiCSharp/Program.cs

I have tried this approach and it works.

**Please mark my answer verified if i were helpful**